# Jolt to convert json array into single element

Tags: jolt

Shown below are 2 records in the JSON document ( i will have more than 2 ) :

```
[{
    "abc": [{
        "value": 44.636914,
        "testName": "1 Month",
        "date": "2020-02-14"
    },
    {
        "value": -0.117243,
        "testName": "1 Week",
        "date": "2020-01-21"    
    }],
    "currency": "CAD",
    "date2": "2020-01-14",
    "id": "W38450"
}
{
    "abc": [{
        "value": -0.873175,
        "testName": "1 Month",
        "date": "2020-02-14"
    },
    {
        "value": 0.005599,
        "testName": "1 Week",
        "date": "2020-01-21"    
    },
    {
        "value": 0.001231,
        "testName": "11 Week",
        "date": "2020-02-21"    
    }],
    "currency": "CAD",
    "date2": "2020-01-14",
    "id": "W38209"
}]
```

i would like to use jolt to convert the array in "abc" as a single value

desired output:

```
[{
    "abc": "[{'value': 44.636914,'testName': '1 Month','date': '2020-02-14'},{'value': -0.117243,'testName': '1 Week','date': '2020-01-21'}]",
    "currency": "CAD",
    "date2": "2020-01-14",
    "id": "W38450"
}
{
    "abc": "[{'value': -0.873175,'testName': '1 Month','date': '2020-02-14'},{'value': 0.005599,'testName': '1 Week','date': '2020-01-21'},{'value': 0.001231,'testName': '11 Week','date': '2020-02-21'}]",
    "currency": "CAD",
    "date2": "2020-01-14",
    "id": "W38209"
}]
```

Note that the array size of "abc" is not constant and i think it is necessarily to change double quote (") to single quote (') as well. 
please advice a solution using Jolt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample of stucture. Now what left to do is to combine with concat function.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "abc": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "$": "[&4].toConcat[&2]",
              "@": "[&4].toConcat[&2]"
            }
          }
        },
        "currency": "[&1].currency",
        "date2": "[&1].date2",
        "id": "[&1].id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "abc": "=join(',',@(1,toConcat))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: With this sample  of structure, i am actually not getting "value" , "testname" and "date" from my original document.

Comment: i am actually getting only the values from the array elements. please help 
`[ {
  "toConcat" : [ [ 44.636914, "1 Month", "2020-02-14" ], [ -0.117243, "1 Week", "2020-01-21" ] ],
  "currency" : "CAD",
  "date2" : "2020-01-14",
  "id" : "W38450"
}, {
  "toConcat" : [ [ -0.873175, "1 Month", "2020-02-14" ], [ 0.005599, "1 Week", "2020-01-21" ], [ 0.001231, "11 Week", "2020-02-21" ] ],
  "currency" : "CAD",
  "date2" : "2020-01-14",
  "id" : "W38209"
} ]`

Comment: Ok, I added LHS values to the field toConcat, but it is not formatted. Does it help you in some way?